# using parameters.json file instead of -TemplateParameterObject in Azure Runbook Arm deployments

Tags: azure

In this example here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-deploy-template-runbook

They use a `-TemplateParameterObject` `$Parameters` for passing parameters to an ARM template. What is the syntax to use a parameters.json file instead?

**Deploy the storage account**

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -TemplateFile $TemplateFile -TemplateParameterObject $Parameters
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `-TemplateParameterFile` parameter to pass the file:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -TemplateFile $TemplateFile -TemplateParameterFile "yourFilePath"
```

You can read more about the cmdlet in the [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/new-azurermresourcegroupdeployment?view=azurermps-4.4.1).

Comment: I tried that but it seems to ignore it: #                                                 
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -TemplateFile $TemplateFile -TemplateParameterFile $TemplateParametersFile

Comment: that worked okay, not sure why it didn't a few minutes earlier. Thanks